# Adicionar um elemento que não está na array

Tags: c, array, lista

Sou novato em C, venho tentando achar uma forma de fazer este programa mas sempre retorna um resultado que não consigo compreender ao printar a array  para visualização.
Exemplo de valores inseridos: 1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6 (99 para parar o programa)
Gostaria que esta fosse a saída: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Mas retorna isto: -1,6,40,0,4203721,0,3,0
Há alguma forma mais simples de fazer isto?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  int valor,vet[10],i;
  while(1)
  {
    printf("valor:");
    scanf("%d",&valor);
    if(valor==99)
    {
      break;
    }
    int c=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

      if(vet[1]==valor)
      {
        c++;
      }
    }
    int cc=0;
    if(c==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cc++;
        }
        vet[cc] = valor;
    }

    }



  for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", vet[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tem varias coisas ai que não fazem sentido. Você quer fazer o que exatamente ? Ir adicionando elementos no fim do array ? Se for isso é bem simples, e consegue faze-lo apenas numa instrução: `vet[ultima_posicao++] = valor;`. Sendo que precisa de inicializar essa ultima posicao para 0 no inicio do programa. Naturalmente também tem de testar se já inseriu mais que a quantidade disponivel, caso contrário terá comportamento indefinido

Comment: Sim, mas o programa não deve adicionar elementos repetidos. Vou tentar usar essa forma que você ensinou para adicionar

Comment: Você precisa controlar qual a posição atual de inserção no vetor e testar se o valor lido já existe dentre estas posições. Da maneira como fez você tenta testar todos os números do array ao inserir o primeiro número. Além disso creio que trocou o `i` por `1`. Focê faz um loop para incrementar a variável `cc` que sempre valerá `10`ao final do loop, o que é um índice inválido para o array.

Comment: Entendi amigo, muito obrigado. Vou procurar estudar mais, é que eu estou em cima da hora pra entregar um projeto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comecemos pelo que não está certo.

Aqui você enganou-se e usou `1` em vez de `i`:

```
if(vet[1]==valor)
{
    c++;
}
```

Mais abaixo fez um `for` que não é util:

```
int cc=0;
if(c==0)
{
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cc++;
    }
    vet[cc] = valor;
}
```

Repare que está a contar sempre a mesma quantidade de elementos no `for`, que são 10. Independentemente dos valores que lá estão e adiciona o elemento numa posição invalida, fora do array. Em vez disso você quer ir adicionando do inicio, e aumentando uma unidade a cada vez que insere.

Vamos corrigir esses dois pontos que mencionei, mantendo o código o mais parecido com o que tinha:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int valor,vet[10],i, ultima_posicao = 0; //variavel para ultima posicao começa a 0
    while(1) {
        printf("valor:");
        scanf("%d",&valor);
        if(valor==99) {
            break;
        }
        int c=0;
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(vet[i]==valor) {
                c++;
            }
        }

        if(c==0) {
            vet[ultima_posicao++] = valor; //apenas isto para inserir o valor
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < ultima_posicao; i++) { //mostra só até os que inseriu
        printf("%d ", vet[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A instrução `vet[ultima_posicao++] = valor;` permite-lhe colocar o valor na posição certa, e aumenta-la para que na próxima inserção fique também no local correto.

Pessoalmente acho que fica bem mais organizado, se criar uma função para verificar se o valor existe no array. E facilita até a nível de lógica, uma vez que nem precisa de contar, e pode fazer `return` direto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int existe(int vet[10], int valor) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(vet[i]==valor) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int valor,vet[10],i, ultima_posicao = 0;
    while(1) {
        printf("valor:");
        scanf("%d",&valor);
        if(valor==99) {
            break;
        }
        if(!existe(vet, valor)) {
            vet[ultima_posicao++] = valor;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < ultima_posicao; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vet[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/3LmShj)

Não coloquei aqui na resposta, mas é útil também prevenir o usuário de inserir mais valores dos que o tamanho do array. Pode fazer isso testando se a variável `ultima_posicao` tem o valor 10 ou mais, e nesse caso terminar o programa.

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado. Vou treinar mais programar arrays, sempre foi meu ponto fraco

Comment: @taynan Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar. Bom treino :)